# Progressive Web App - How to store image/file into mobile's gallery?

Tags: asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a PWA(for Android & iOS mobile user), which would store a taken photo into mobile device(gallery). How can I store the photo into mobile device's gallery?

Take Photo:-

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

I'd like to know how can I achieve that?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I would like to know how you solved this as well :D